# Read json in different ways using pig

Tags: dictionary, schema, tuples, apache-pig

**my json file**

> ```
> {"messages":[{"food":"Taco1", "person":"Alice1", "amount":1}]}
> {"messages":[{"food":"Taco2", "person":"Alice2", "amount":2}]}
> {"messages":[{"food":"Taco3", "person":"Alice3", "amount":3}]}
> ```

**my code**

```
STOCK_A = LOAD 'file.json' 
USING JsonLoader('messages:{(food:chararray, person:chararray, amount:int)}');
rowarr = FOREACH STOCK_A GENERATE FLATTEN(messages.(food, person,amount));
```

**result schema**

```
rowarr: {null::food: chararray,null::person: chararray,null::amount: int}
```

**expected**

```
rowarr: {food: chararray,person: chararray,amount: int}
```

How can I acheive this? Any idea

Comment: `foreach ... generate null::food as food` etc etc... Or directly `FOREACH STOCK_A GENERATE FLATTEN(messages.(food, person,amount)) as (food, person, amount);`

Comment: It s worked..Thanks Balduz